# SSAS Tabular vs Multidimensional: can the Excel user tell the difference?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

When I say "tell the difference" I mean to exclude performance considerations.

I understand there are many important differences for the developer of the model, but I have found no clear guidance on this question: Is the consumer of the model (eg. in Excel) indifferent to these distinctions?

Thank you!

Comment: Multidimensional from my experience is going to take a significant amount of time to process (especially MOLAP). That latency/performance issue will show up in refreshing data in excel sheets that have larger data sizes. As far as the consumer of the model seeing differences between the two there really isn't any, unless the consumers use different versions of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Multidimensional from my experience is going to take a significant amount of time to process (especially MOLAP). That latency/performance issue will show up in refreshing data in excel sheets that have larger data sizes. As far as the consumer of the model seeing differences between the two there really isn't any, unless the consumers use different versions of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the consumer of the model (eg. in Excel) indifferent to these distinctions?

Yes.  But Excel is an MDX client.  For the most part It Just Works™, but sometimes the MDX it generates performs more poorly than what a DAX client would generate.  And tabular doesn't support offline cubes.